# database connect issues

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, xampp

Hello could anyone help me please with db connection, im using xampp, phpmyadmin, when i open the browser, DBConnection.class.php it shows blank and db doesnt work, thanks

```
<?php 
    class DBConnection{
        public static function DbConn(){
            $servername = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test";
            $username = "root";
            $password = "";
        try{
            $conn = new PDO($servername, $username, $password);
            return $conn;
            echo"Connection succesful :)";
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Connection failed :( :" . $e->getMessage();
        }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: why you call this `DBConnection` class?

Comment: i dont know, just a name of the file

Comment: Well no, if you're looking at a class in your browser, you're not going to see anything. This does nothing but define a class. You aren't using it yet.

Answer (score -1):

Modified Code. Try this:

```
class DBConnection{
    public static function DbConn(){
        $servername = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
    try{
        $conn = new PDO($servername, $username, $password);
        return "Connection succesfull :)";
        //return $conn;

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed :( :" . $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
}
```

and then call like this

```
$Connection =  new DBConnection();
print_r($Connection->DbConn());
```

Comment: Modified answer. Please try that. If still not working check your db connection details